# How to add motion blur to already rendered image sequence?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, motion-capture, motion-blur

I have an image sequence that I need to make less choppy. I didn't add it while rendering.

I know there is a script for it [here.](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?318485-Motion-Blur-Script-for-Blender-VSE)

but I am not sure if it's the best way to go at it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Find some way to use Optical Flow, Blender doesn't have it.